# Neural network sometimes predicting only one class: suggestions?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, deep-learning

When training a neural net on a (somewhat balanced) dataset, the neural network will occasionally (1/3 of the time) get locked in predicting only one class. I've reduced the size of the layers as much as I can, so I'm looking for some suggestions as to

- The type of optimizer and learning rate (I've tried SGD, Adam, Adadelta, etc. at varying learning rates)
- What initializers I should try for each layer (e.g. glorot normal, random, etc.)
- Any other learning strategies you can think of

The networks takes in a matrix of data as primary input and a vector as auxiliary. It outputs one of four classes.

Thanks so much!

Comment: You need to provide some information on your input and output data